# How to show menu bar in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

The menu bar in notepad++  is missing. I have tried to remove plugins, even reinstate the program, still menu bar is hidden. Any ideas ?

Comment: This question is _not_ a duplicate.  It asks about how to use Notepad++ when it is working properly.  The other question refers to a bug in which the menu bar continues to disappear.

Comment: How do I down-vote the people who decided to mark this as a duplicate?   The correct answer is F12, but I'm not sure what the correct question is.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Menu Bar can be turned on and off in Settings -> Preferences.  Since the bar is missing, you can open the Settings menu by pressing ALT-t.

If the Title Bar is missing along with the Menu Bar, it may be in Full Screen mode and/or Post-It mode.  Press F11 and/or F12 to toggle Full Screen and Post-It modes, respectively.

Comment: For completeness the Setting is -  Settings->General->(below)Tab Bar->Hide menu bar (Use Alt or F10 key to toggle)

Comment: Sometimes F11 does not work. Use F12 in that case.

Comment: @Wikis has the correct answer, and I think there's something wrong with the duplicate flag.

Comment: Thanks, @pabrams! F11 is "Toggle Full Screen Mode", and F12 is " Toggle Post-It Mode". Either mode will hide the title bar. So, depending on which mode you're in, either F11 or F12 might be appropriate. I'll add this to the answer tomorrow.

Comment: This doesn't work in linux

Comment: @RanchiRhino Notepad++ isn't a Linux application. You can run it in wine, but Linux intercepts the Fn keys before they get through to the application...